# StimulusJS Target is undefined but .querySelector works

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, stimulusjs

I'm confused. I'm getting some inconsistent behaviour with a target in a stimulus controller.

Using StimulusJS via importmap `pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js", preload: true`

I have a basic form with stimulus controller.

```rb
<%= form_with model: @message, data: { controller: "message-form" } do |form| %>

  <%= form.file_field :attachments, class: 'file-input', id: 'file-input', multiple: true, hidden: "hidden",
                      data: { message_form_target: "attachmentInput" } %>

  <i class="fa-solid fa-paperclip fa-lg" data-action="click->message-form#openAttachments"></i>


<% end %>
```

```js
import {Controller} from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
    static targets = ["messageInput", "sendBtn", "attachmentInput"]

    connect() {
        this.inputIsEmpty()
        console.log(this.attachmentInputTarget) // Outputs HTML element
    }

    openAttachments(){
        this.attachmentInputTarget.click()
        this.attachmentInputTarget.removeAttribute("hidden")
        setInterval(this.hideAttachments, 5000)
    }

    hideAttachments(){
        let attachmentInput = document.querySelector('#file-input')
        console.log(this.attachmentInputTarget) // Undefined
        console.log(attachmentInput) // Outputs HTML element
        console.log(document.getElementById('file-input') == this.attachmentInputTarget) // false

        if (!document.getElementById('file-input').files[0]) {
            attachmentInput.setAttribute("hidden", "hidden")
        } else {
            attachmentInput.removeAttribute("hidden")
        }
    }
}
```

So, `attatchmentInputTarget` in connect() acts as I would expect it to and outputs the HTML element, but when `hideAttachments` is called `attatchmentInputTarget` is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, as I've written this all out I figured it out.

Because of the delayed call with `setInterval`, `hideAttachments` gets called outside of the stimulus controller as vanilla JS, so has no reference to the Target.

Comment: How did you solve the problem?